# Any way to call Excel functions in VB.NET as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel throws Class not registered (REGB_E_CLASSNOTREG) in Server?

Tags: vb.net, com-interop, excel-interop

The application needs to use some Excel functions (NormSDist, NormSInv) to calculate some result. There is slight difference between the results by Excel and .NET equivalent of these functions. As it is a banking application the user wants exact match. So by referring Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and calling Excel functions NormSDist, NormSInv return exact result.

By referring Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

```
Dim appExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
Dim wsf As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetFunction = appExcel.WorksheetFunction()

decOne = wsf.NormSInv(someValue) + wsf.NormSInv(someValue)
decTwo = 12.5 * wsf.NormSDist(decNorm)
```

.NET equivalent functions

```
Public Shared Function NORMSDIST(z As Double) As Double
    Dim sign As Double = 1
    If z < 0 Then
        sign = -1
    End If
    Return 0.5 * (1.0 + sign * erf(Math.Abs(z) / Math.Sqrt(2)))
End Function

Private Shared Function erf(x As Double) As Double
    Dim a1 As Double = 0.254829592
    Dim a2 As Double = -0.284496736
    Dim a3 As Double = 1.421413741
    Dim a4 As Double = -1.453152027
    Dim a5 As Double = 1.061405429
    Dim p As Double = 0.3275911
    x = Math.Abs(x)
    Dim t As Double = 1 / (1 + p * x)
    Return 1 - ((((((a5 * t + a4) * t) + a3) * t + a2) * t) + a1) * t * Math.Exp(-1 * x * x)
End Function

' This function is a replacement for the Microsoft Excel Worksheet function NORMSINV.
' It uses the algorithm of Peter J. Acklam to compute the inverse normal cumulative
' distribution. Refer to http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/index.html for
' a description of the algorithm.
' Adapted to VB by Christian d'Heureuse, http://www.source-code.biz.
Public Shared Function NormSInv(ByVal p As Double) As Double
    Const a1 = -39.6968302866538, a2 = 220.946098424521, a3 = -275.928510446969
    Const a4 = 138.357751867269, a5 = -30.6647980661472, a6 = 2.50662827745924
    Const b1 = -54.4760987982241, b2 = 161.585836858041, b3 = -155.698979859887
    Const b4 = 66.8013118877197, b5 = -13.2806815528857, c1 = -0.00778489400243029
    Const c2 = -0.322396458041136, c3 = -2.40075827716184, c4 = -2.54973253934373
    Const c5 = 4.37466414146497, c6 = 2.93816398269878, d1 = 0.00778469570904146
    Const d2 = 0.32246712907004, d3 = 2.445134137143, d4 = 3.75440866190742
    Const p_low = 0.02425, p_high = 1 - p_low
    Dim q As Double, r As Double
    Dim strErrMsg As String = ""

    If p < 0 Or p > 1 Then
        strErrMsg = "NormSInv: Argument out of range."
    ElseIf p < p_low Then
        q = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(p))
        NormSInv = (((((c1 * q + c2) * q + c3) * q + c4) * q + c5) * q + c6) /
     ((((d1 * q + d2) * q + d3) * q + d4) * q + 1)
    ElseIf p <= p_high Then
        q = p - 0.5 : r = q * q
        NormSInv = (((((a1 * r + a2) * r + a3) * r + a4) * r + a5) * r + a6) * q /
     (((((b1 * r + b2) * r + b3) * r + b4) * r + b5) * r + 1)
    Else
        q = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(1 - p))
        NormSInv = -(((((c1 * q + c2) * q + c3) * q + c4) * q + c5) * q + c6) /
     ((((d1 * q + d2) * q + d3) * q + d4) * q + 1)
    End If
End Function
```

But as Excel is not in the server, it throws

`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID{} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))`

Is there any way to use Excel functions in .NET or is there any library to consume these Excel functions?

Note: This application just requires the Excel functions and it doesn't interact with any excel files

Comment: I checked http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelFinancialFunctions/ but it doesn't have NormSDist, NormSInv methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathNet.Numerics library (https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) works as expected.

`Install-Package MathNet.Numerics -Version 3.20.0`

In .vb file,

```
Imports MathNet.Numerics
```

As ExcelFunctions is a static class, directly call the methods as

```
decOne = ExcelFunctions.NormSInv(someValue) + ExcelFunctions.NormSInv(someValue)
decTwo = 12.5 * ExcelFunctions.NormSDist(decNorm)
```

The below link has the list of methods available
https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/ExcelFunctions.htm